# Build and deploy web app on nix system without Visual Studio

Tags: git, visual-studio, unix, asp.net-core, web-applications

We develop ASP.NET Core web application using Visual Studio under Windows. Is here any possibility to build and deploy web application from source code under .nix systems with Git and without Visual Studio? What i should learn on this issue? Are here any scripts to do the job?

Comment: You mean like command line `dotnet build`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.NET Core is totally cross-platform, which means, of course, so is ASP.NET Core when targeting .NET Core. The .NET Core SDK includes the `dotnet` command which can be used to generate projects from templates, build and run your apps, publish, etc. In fact, Visual Studio merely proxies to this `dotnet` command-line tool to do its own work.

That, then, just leaves your development environment. Since, ultimately, you're just dealing with text files, you can use whatever editor you like, even something like VIM. Now, development wouldn't be much fun with that approach, though, because you'd miss out on all the things like syntax highlighting, autocompletion, etc. As a result, it's probably better to use something like Visual Studio Code, which is also cross-platform, and buys you these features plus many more.